# Run zprint-cli recursively on multiple files in nested directories via NPM scripts

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, npm-scripts, edn

**Goal:** Use npm scripts to run `zprint-clj` on each file with the appropriate file extension in a bundle of nested folders.

`zprint-clj` expects a filename in and a filename out each time it's run. eg: `zprint-clj -i <filein.ext> -o <fileout.ext>`

I'm having difficulty understanding how to recursively run the command/script on each file with the matching file extension. The tutorials and guides I've found don't seem to deal with libraries that require specific files be typed out with the library command.

I am still new to this process, so I may be overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

You're not overlooking something obvious. It's rather a case of the feature that you want simply doesn't exist.

Unfortunately [zprint-clj](https://github.com/roman01la/zprint-clj) does not provide an option to recursively process `.clj` files in a bundle of nested folders. It only accepts one input file per usage.

Perhaps you should post a request for this feature to be added in the projects GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/roman01la/zprint-clj/issues).

Meanwhile, to meet your requirement you could consider creating a custom node script which utilizes `zprint-cli`. This script can then be invoked via your `npm script`.

---

### Long answer with solution:

The following demonstrates a solution to fulfill your requirement.

#### 1. Additional packages

Firstly you'll need to `cd` to your project directory and install some additional packages locally via npm *(Note: we'll also include references to these packages in the `devDependencies` section of `package.json`)*:

1. Install [cli-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-glob) by running:

   ```
   npm i -D cli-glob
   ```
2. Next, install [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) by running:

   ```
   npm i -D shelljs
   ```
3. And, if you haven't got it installed locally already, install [zprint-clj](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zprint-clj) by running:

   ```
   npm i -D zprint-clj
   ```

#### 2. Custom node script

Next create a custom node script as follows. Let's name the file `recursive-zprint.js` and save it to a hidden directory named `.scripts` in the root of your project folder.

```
    project
    ├─── .scripts
    │    └─── recursive-zprint.js
    ├─── node_modules
    └─── ...
```

**recursive-zprint.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');
const shelljs = require('shelljs');

const TICK = process.platform === 'win32' ? '√' : '✔';

var outputDir = '';
var verbose = false;

// Setup interface to read glob paths piped to stdin.
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: null,
  terminal: false
});

// Read each line from process.stdin
// (i.e. the filepath for each .clj found via the glob pattern)
rl.on('line', function (filePath) {
  formatData(filePath);
});

// Handle the optional `-o` argument for the output dir.
if (process.argv.indexOf('-o') !== -1) {
  outputDir = process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('-o') + 1];
}

// Handle the optional `-v` argument for verbose logging.
if (process.argv.indexOf('-v') !== -1) {
  verbose = true;
}

/**
 * Gets the path to node_modules/.bin executable.
 * @param {string} command - The executable name
 * @returns {string} The path to the executable.
 */
function getBin(command) {
  return path.join('node_modules', '.bin', command);
}

/**
 * Obtains the destination path for where the formated file should be saved.
 * Creates directories, and executes the zprint command . If the `-o` argument
 * is not specified via the npm-script the original file is overwritten.
 *
 * @param {String} srcPath - The path to the source file.
 */
function formatData(srcPath) {
  const destPath = getDestPath(srcPath);
  makeDirectory(path.dirname(destPath));
  shelljs.exec(getBin('zprint-clj') + ' -i ' + srcPath + ' -o ' + destPath);

  // Log formatted filepath to console.
  if (verbose) {
    shelljs.echo('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', TICK, destPath);
  }
}

/**
 * Obtains destination path for where to save the formatted file. Joins the
 * source path, excluding the root directory, with the given output path.
 *
 * @param {String} srcPath - The path to the source file.
 * @return {String} - The destination file path.
 */
function getDestPath(srcPath) {
  if (outputDir) {
    const parts = srcPath.split(path.sep);
    parts.shift();
    return path.join(outputDir,  parts.join(path.sep));
  }
  return srcPath;
}

/**
 * Create a new directory and intermediate directories if necessary.
 * @param {String} dirPath - The path for the directory.
 */
function makeDirectory(dirPath) {
  if (!shelljs.test('-d', dirPath)) {
    shelljs.mkdir('-p', dirPath);
  }
}
```

---

#### 3. Configuring npm-scripts

Configure your [npm-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) as follows. Lets name the script `zprint`:

***Overwriting the original files...***`

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "zprint": "glob \"src/**/*.clj\" | node .scripts/recursive-zprint"
  },
  ...
}
```

Note the following:

1. The script above utilizes `cli-glob` to obtain the path to each `.clj` file stored in the `src` directory many levels deep. You'll need to replace the `\"src/**/*.clj\"` part with a glob pattern suitable for your project.
2. The list of files found by the glob pattern are then piped to the custom node script (i.e. `recursive-zprint.js`).
3. All original source `.clj` using this configuration will be overwritten with the formatted data.

***Avoid overwriting the original files...***

To avoid overwriting the original `.clj` files `recursive-zprint.js` allows an optional `-o` argument to be passed via the script that specified the output directory.

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "zprint": "glob \"src/**/*.clj\" | node .scripts/recursive-zprint -o \"path/to/output\""
  },
  ...
}
```

Note the following:

1. This example configuration includes the additonal `-o` argument followed by the path to where the formatted files will be saved.
2. If you're going to use the `-o` argument you'll again need to replace the `\"path/to/output\"` part with a suitable output path for your project.

#### 4. Source directory vs resultant directory

Given the last npm script configuration shown (the one which utilizes the `-o` argument). Lets assume we have a `src` directory with files as follows:

```
    project
    ├─── src
    │   ├─── a.clj
    │   ├─── x
    │   │   ├─── b.clj
    │   │   └─── y
    │   │       └─── c.clj
    │   └─── d.clj
    └─── ...
```

Afer running `npm run zprint`, via your CLI, the resultant output will be as follows *(Note the original source sub directories are preserved in the resultant output)*:

```
    project
    ├─── path
    │   └─── to
    │       └─── output
    │           ├─── a.clj
    │           ├─── x
    │           │   ├─── b.clj
    │           │   └─── y
    │           │       └─── c.clj
    │           └─── d.clj
    ├─── src
    │   └─── ... (same as before)
    └─── ...
```

#### 5. Verbose logging

If you want to log to the console the path of each file when it has been formatted successfully you can add the `-v` optional argument too. For example:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "zprint": "glob \"src/**/*.clj\" | node .scripts/recursive-zprint -v -o \"path/to/output\""
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: This was an amazing help, thank you! This was an incredible walkthrough. Very informative, easy to follow. My only note would be the addition of leading and trailing slashes for `/path/to/output/`. At least, in my case I needed them. :)